# Data Import Wizard: There was a problem uploading the CSV file. Try again, or choose another file

Tags: csv, data-import-wizard

I'm trying to import a very simple .CSV file with the Data Import Wizard:

```
FNAME,LNAME,CELL,EMAIL,SALUTATION,TITLE 
Andrea,Ianni,555-888-8888,aianni@example.com,Mr.,CEO
Benedetta,Siniscalchi,555-999-8888,ssnith@example.com,Ms.,Senior Sales Rep
Gioele,Ianni,555-999-0000,gdapper@example.com,Dr.,Director of Healthcare
Laura,Paglia,555-888-8888,jdodge2@example.com,Mr.,EVP of Sales
```

I follow the steps:
1) What kind of data are you importing? ==> Accounts and Contacts
2) What do you want to do? ==> Add new records
3) Where is your data located?

When I choose my .CSV file the system gives me back the error:

**There was a problem uploading the CSV file. Try again, or choose another file.**

Does a *typical* solution exist?

Comment: I highly recommend a short YouTube series called [Data Import How To's](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnobS_RgN7JZaD_Fq8uh3b2AA8olsj1Qk). The 2nd an 3rd one in the series should help you sort out your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I've tried different browsers, different text editors, etc. etc. I finally found the problem: it is a "bug" in Salesforce.

The import of the contacts fails when the **Lightning Components** is *enabled*.
You can find it in the Known Issues: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XEqAAM.

Solution: **Temporarily disable lightning components**.

1. Setup -> Develop -> Lightning Components
2. Disable it.
3. Try the import again.

Answer (score 1):

I have used your file and it uploaded successfully. Please find the screenshots. I think you have to MAP 3 field (screenshot 3) names accordingly. Click on MAP and choose the file accordingly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately my system stops at the first screenshot. Where you see "Drag CSV file here to upload" I get the error message. Anyways, if you can upload my file at least I know the problem is not in the file itself. I'll keep trying. Thanks!

Comment: I have not used drag and drop, used "Choose file" instead. You can try also.

Comment: About the .CSV file, did you create it from Excel or from OpenOffice Calc?

Comment: I just copied your content in notepad and saved as .csv. You have to select all file types in second dropdown.

Comment: I tried to do it with excel, notepad (saving it with the .csv extension) and also OpenOffice Calc.... but I have the same issue.

Comment: Try from a different browser, if possible from another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing symbols from my .csv file. Once I removed all of these - "▯" - it worked.